# find command use

Tags: bash, find

I'm struggling using the find command that will allow me to find all files that were modified over 7 days ago and that are larger than 1 MB.

Here's what I have -

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +7 | -size +1M
```

But I don't think this is the right syntax.

Comment: read the fine manual.  http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/find/

Comment: on most systems you really can access the man pages offline. You may try `man find`

Answer (score 7):

Please try the next line

```
find /path/to/files -mtime +7 -size +1M
```

Comment: You have to prepend `7` and `1M` with a `+` sign

Answer (score 6):

The bar `|` is interpreted by your shell. Try the following

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +7 -a -size +1M
```

Comment: `-and` is not portable and actually does nothing in this case. `-and` is implied.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Changed `-and` to `-a`. I think a visible operator makes the statement more legible.